# Java Filter algorithm. Why non-volatile variables are used?

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm reading chapter 2 of "[The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123973376)" and I'm confused about Filter algorithm which looks like so:

```
class Filter implements Lock {
    int[] level;
    int[] victim;
    public Filter(int n) {
        level = new int[n];
        victim = new int[n]; // use 1..n-1
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            level[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    public void lock() {
        int me = ThreadID.get();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { //attempt level 1
            level[me] = i;
            victim[i] = me;
            // spin while conflicts exist
            while (( ∃ k != me) (level[k] >= i && victim[i] == me)) {};
        }
    }
    public void unlock() {
        int me = ThreadID.get();
        level[me] = 0;
    }
}
```

What looks strange to me, is that `level` and `victim` arrays are not made `volatile`. Prior to this algorithm, the author presented less general "Peterson algorithm", where variables are set like so:

```
private volatile boolean[] flag = new boolean[2];
private volatile int victim;
```

So my question is why in a more general algorithm we do not specify `level` and `victim` as `volatile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly `volatile` is like `final` or `static` in that it only applies to the field, not the object referenced. e.g.

```
volatile int[] level;
```

means writes to `level` not `level[0]` are volatile.

In fact there is no way to do this in natural Java which is why `AtomicIntegerArray` uses `Unsafe` to perform volatile and thread safe operations.

In short, the only real solution is to use `AtomicIntegerArray` (or `Unsafe` directly).

Comment: Does it mean, that in "Filter algorithm" we'd better use `AtomicIntegerArray` instead of `int[]`?

Comment: @Jacobian That is my view, which is why AtomicIntegerArray was added.